# Will not process to the next line

Tags: excel, vba

Ok here it is, I have this VBA code in Excel that I am trying to take certain data from one tab to another tab and edit that data. I am getting almost everything to complete except when I run it I get a dialog box that comes up and says "Select Range". It should take the data in the selected cell and add it to the end of a given URL, with the cell Value shown, so that when clicked it will take you to the page with the given ID and URL combined.

Here is the code:

```
'Hyperlink column A
Dim WorkRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Dim l As Long
Dim addr As String
For l = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Value <> "" Then
        addr = CStr("https://att.agilecraft.com/RequestGrid?FirstTime=True&RequestID=") & CStr(WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Value)
        WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WorkRng.Cells(l, 1), _
        Address:=addr, _
        TextToDisplay:=CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    End If
Next l
```

This refuses to go to the next line till it reaches the last row.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The code works fine. Select the range of cells and then run your macro. It added links to the cell for me. If you select a single cell, it will just make a link for that cell.

Comment: it only adds the link to the one line its suppose to move to the next line and do the samething

Comment: Do you have a single cell selected? Add this line before the Set WorkRng.. `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` . It will select the range and then turn them to hyperlinks.

Comment: Sweet tyvm I know I was missing something simple, this works great, tyvm